# How to run PenAndPdf project in Android

Tags: android, c, kotlin

So Pen and Pdf is an open source PDFViewer/Annotater app for android and other platforms. It is written on top of MuPDF and as such is written in C. When I get the code from github and add it to android studio it gives me all kinds of problems. How to I run the project?

[Pen And Pdf](https://github.com/cgogolin/penandpdf)

Comment: Adding C code to an Android project is not trivial. Did you follow the steps here? https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code

Comment: I did. And it throws this error: GNUMAKE: Expected exactly one source file in compile step.

Sometimes it throws *** no make rules found and other stuff.